# Sum a column based on condition in another column in R

Tags: r, count, sum

I have a dataset with 150+ columns and 1000s of rows. The dataset provides a flag for different items for various categories in different columns. One of the columns is total usage for each item across the category. Below is sample of the dataset:

```
Values   A B C
1        Y   
2          Y
3        Y   Y 
4            Y
```

I want to use R to do calculations such that I get the following results:

```
     Count  Sum
A      2     4
B      1     2
C      2     7
```

Basically I want the Count Column to give me the number of "y" for A, B and C, and the Sum column to give me sum from the Usage column for each time there is a "Y" in Columns A, B and C

Step 2 -  I have similar column values in 200 + files. I have brought all the files into a folder. What I would like to do is use the above functions, apply it in each of the file, and then have the answer grouped by file and category. for example

`File 1 Count A Sum A Count B Sum B Count C Sum C`

`File 2 Count A Sum A Count B Sum B Count C Sum C`

and so on

Answer (score 2):

Here's one simple (step-by-step) solution

```
# First, readind your data
> df <- read.table(text="Values   A  B  C
+ 1        Y  NA NA
+ 2        NA Y  NA
+ 3        Y  NA Y 
+ 4        NA NA Y ", header=TRUE)
> 
> Count <- colSums(!is.na(df[, -1]))
> Sum <- apply(!is.na(df[,-1]), 2, function(x) sum(df$Values[x]))
> data.frame(Count, Sum)
  Count Sum
A     2   4
B     1   2
C     2   7
```

Comment: Jilber - thanks for your help! this worked! can you provide feedback to my second question. I have over 200 files with similar information. I would want to do this formula for each file, and then provide the result by each file. I tried to do a loop, but it is not giving me the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% gather(id, vals, -Values) %>% group_by(id) %>%
        summarise(Count = sum(vals=="Y"), 
                  Sum = sum(Values[vals=="Y"]))
#      id Count   Sum
#  (fctr) (int) (int)
#1      A     2     4
#2      B     1     2
#3      C     2     7
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Values = 1:4, A = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), C = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"Y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Values", "A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Hello All - thank you so much for the quick response! I really appreciate it.allistaire and Jilber - your responses were pretty similar. I am new to R - can you explain to me what df[,-1] does? I am not sure why the -1 was used.

Comment: How do I take this to the next step? I have similar column values in 200 + files. I have brought all the files into a folder. What I would like to do is use the above functions, apply it in each of the file, and then have the answer grouped by file and category. for example File 1 - Count A Sum A Count B Sum B Count C Sum C, File 2 - CCount A Sum A Count B Sum B Count C Sum C and so on. thank you again

Comment: mtoto - i like your feedback, but I am getting an error when I try to replicate your solution. I am getting the error Error: object 'vals' not found. As I understand it, this could be any name, but I am not sure why I getting this error. thank you again for your feedback.

Comment: have you checked the output of `df %>% gather(id, vals, -Values)` ?

Comment: mtoto - thanks now it worked! there was some space between the gather and group_by. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` approach.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), `melt` to 'long' format, grouped by 'id', get the `sum` of 'value' that are "Y" to get the 'Count', subset the 'Values' that corresponds to "Y" element in 'value', `sum` it to get the "Sum".

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), id.var="Values", variable.name="id")[, {
           i1 <- value == "Y"
           .(Count = sum(i1), Sum = sum(Values[i1]))
           } ,  by = id]
#   id Count Sum
#1:  A     2   4
#2:  B     1   2
#3:  C     2   7
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easiest to just build a new data.frame from calculations on the old one:

```
# read in data
df <- read.table(text = 'Values   A B C
                         1        Y N N 
                         2        N Y N
                         3        Y N Y 
                         4        N N Y', header = TRUE)

data.frame(Count = colSums(df[,-1] == 'Y'),    # count of "Y"s in each column
           # sum of Values column where A/B/C is "Y"
           Sum = sapply(df[,-1], function(x){sum(df$Values[x == 'Y'])}))

#   Count Sum
# A     2   4
# B     1   2
# C     2   7
```